# REST and WSDualHttpBinding - Duplex Possibilities

Tags: c#, wcf, duplex

as it stands i have a REST service setup with a WebHttpBinding, all is fine. What i want to do is now is create a duplex connection but REST being REST it doesn't look like a return channel is at all possible.

So my questions are -

a. is there any way to use REST in a duplex fashion

b. if not (as i suspect) what other options are there to maintain the REST binding and add a new endpoint to the service which can handle the client duplex communication?